# Where can i find the latest ionic-angular2 version in a plunker that uses @Ngmodule?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am learning `ionic 2` from here.
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/project-structure/
I check there is online editor for ionic 2 with  simple example .

https://plnkr.co/edit/SJ8GtqbRntby5yGzLEft?p=preview
.But example not used `Ngmodule` .I think plunker is `old`.can we make this same example using latest `ionic 2` version using **Ngmodule**.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyApp,HelloIonicPage, ItemDetailsPage, ListPage],
  imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [MyApp,HelloIonicPage,ItemDetailsPage,ListPage],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule 
{}
```

can we make hello world program with latest ionic version in plunker

Comment: I think thats more of a ionic thing and not a framework ? Its hard to replicate the full routing of a mobile app within a browser.

Comment: ok ..I just need `hello world` uisng ionic 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at my **[Plunker Example ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.1](https://plnkr.co/edit/1iXlhFfzg8cLnI0o6cmn?p=preview)**

**Systemjs config** looks like:

```
(function(global) {
  var packages = {
    app: {
      main: './main.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    rxjs: {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'ionic-angular': {
      main: 'index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  };

  ['core',
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router'
  ].forEach(function (name) {
    packages['@angular/' + name] = { main: 'index.js' };
  });

  var config = {
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {
      emitDecoratorMetadata: true
    },
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
    },
    map: {
      'app': 'src',
      '@angular': 'npm:@angular',
      'ionic-angular': 'npm:ionic-angular',
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'typescript': 'npm:typescript/lib/typescript.js'
    },
    //packages defines our app package
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Hope this will help you in your coding!

Answer (score 1):

As of to this date, [this plunker seems to work, version: **ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.4**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZsoPeE?p=preview)

**This is the Systemjs config:**

```
/**
 * PLUNKER VERSION
 * (based on systemjs.config.js in angular.io)
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    // DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      tsconfig: true
    },
    meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    },
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      pages: 'pages',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core@2.2.1/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common@2.2.1/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler@2.2.1/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.2.1/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.2.1/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http@2.2.1/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms@2.2.1/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      'ionic-angular': 'npm:ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.4',
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12',
      'ts': 'npm:plugin-typescript@5.3.1/lib/plugin.js',
      'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.10/lib/typescript.js',

    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.ts',
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
      },
      pages: {
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ionic-angular': {
        main: './umd/index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);


/*
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

**And tsconfig:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one I created: http://plnkr.co/edit/y8R0MF?p=info

Updated to Ionic 3.2.1 and angular 4.2.2 It's stupid simple but works

```
// angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core@4.1.2/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common@4.1.2/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler@4.1.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser@4.1.2/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.1.2/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http@4.1.2/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms@4.1.2/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      'ionic-angular': 'npm:ionic-angular@3.2.1',
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12',
      'ts': 'npm:plugin-typescript@5.2.7/lib/plugin.js',
      'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.7/lib/typescript.js',

    },
```